# Worklight - Unable to Download App - "App Center" could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I code sign the IBM AppCenter client for iOS using my Enterprise Certificate. I used a unique bundle identifier and provisioning profile for the same. The OTA installation works fine in most of the iOS devices.

In few devices iPhone5S powered with iOS 7.1.1, it fails to download and install and gives the error message "Unable to Download App" - App Center could not be installed at this time". I have checked the Code Signing properties in my codebase. Every thing looks fine. Note sure why this fails in few devices and works fine in most of the devices.

[image: Screen Shot - Error Message]

Comment: What Worklight Version are you using?

Comment: iOS 7 requires HTTPS; are you serving the file via HTTPS?

Comment: @OrlandoRincón - Worklight 6.1.1

Comment: @IdanAdar - Yapp, its over HTTPS. Error in few iPhone 5S & C devices powered with iOS 7.1.1

Comment: @IdanAdar - I just created the PMR for the same. i am not able to trace, why this error comes. Our Worklight technical contact from IBM says it fails on subnet of phones. its not an installation issue, more a network/phone/worklight issue. Any idea on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons:

1. as Idan said already, iOS 7.1 requires SSL (https) with a real SSL certificate, that is, self signed certificates don't work. Application Center must run on a server that has a CA authorized SSL certificate that matches the server URL. Earlier versions of iOS did not have this restriction.
2. the app might not be provisioned for the device. This depends on your provisioning profile. Development profiles are limited to preregistered devices. If you are able to side-load the app on the same device, the provisioning profile must be correct. Typically, when the provisioning profiles is wrong, the app appears to be downloaded to ca 75% and then the failure occurs.
3. the Apple server to validate the provisioning profile is not reachable. This happens seldom and is normally not specific to a device. This can only explain occasional random failures to install the app, but it cannot explain when an app fails always on the same device.
4. there might be a connection problem between the Application Center server and the device. In this case, you don't see the download to go to 75% but it stops earlier in the download process. In Worklight 6.1, the Application Center uses resumable downloads, hence a temporary connection problem should normally get resolved automatically. But it can be a permanent connection problem on specific devices. In order to check whether it is a connection problem, you could open the Worklight AppCenter Console on the device inside Safari and try to download any app binary ... The resulting network traffic is similar to the one that occurs during installation.

I hope this helps!